# Creating a batch file - depending on variable, search for file type and extract or move

Tags: batch-file, file-extension, rar

Been trying to create an additional batch script that processes files for me. I either get send 1 or several .pdf test files in a .rar file.

So what I am trying to aim for is:

```
If the first variable 1 is named 'test' then
    Is there a .rar file in the folder from variable 2 then
        Extract to a folder and then delete .rar file
    else
        check that there is a .pdf file and then copy to folder
Else
    Tell the user that neither a file or a archive has been found
```

I've managed to scrape this together but I need help trying to expand it further to include all the options:

```
@echo off
set "cat=%1"
IF "%cat%"=="test" ( for /f %%G in ('dir *.rar /b') do set filename=%%~G)

echo %filename%
```

This only gives me half the file name as they have gaps in the filename, also need to change the dir in the 3rd line to be looking in variable 2 that is sent in.

To add to it I've just been told that it's the same for .txt files, the multiples are sent to me in a .rar file

Comment: The `FOR /F` command separates the output from the IN clause using a space as the delimiter.  So if you want to continue to use that code you have to use the `delimis` option to tell the `FOR /F` command to not use any delimiters: `"delims="`. But you could just use a basic for command instead: `FOR %%G IN (*.rar) do set filename=%%G`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest opening a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/), running `call /?` and reading the output help. The help explains how the arguments – also called options or parameters, but not variables – of a batch file can be referenced from within a batch file.

It is advisable to check if a batch file is called with at least one argument if it must be called with at least one argument and output a help for correct usage of the batch file if it was started without any argument or if it was started with `/?` which is the default on Windows to get help about a command or program.

---

The manual for console version of *WinRAR* is the file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR*. It can be read in this text file after opening it with a double click that `Rar.exe` can extract one or more *.rar archive files found in a directory. For that reason it is not really necessary to use command **FOR**. But it is advisable for this task to use command **FOR** as the RAR file(s) should be deleted after successful extraction of the RAR archive(s).

---

Let us look on the **FOR** command line `for /f %%G in ('dir *.rar /b') do` and what it does on execution.

**FOR** with option `/F` to process a text file content or a single string or the output of a command line results in this case in starting a command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line between the two `'` appended. So executed by the Windows command process `cmd.exe` processing the batch file with `for /F` is the following with Windows installed into `C:\Windows` as by default:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir *.rar /b
```

The command **DIR** executed by separate command process in background

- searches in current directory
- for directory entries (files or directories)
- matching the wildcard pattern `*.rar`
- and not having hidden attribute set (implicit default is `/A-H` on option `/A` not specified at all)
- and outputs to handle **STDOUT** the found directory entries matching the criteria above in bare format line by line which means with just file/folder name without path and never enclosed in double quotes even on containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``.

An error message is output by **DIR** to handle **STDERR** of background command process if it cannot find any directory entry matching the search criteria.

**FOR** respectively the command process processing the batch file redirects the output to handle **STDERR** of the background command process to its own **STDERR** handle which results in getting it displayed in console window in this case. But the output to handle **STDOUT** of started background command process is captured by **FOR** respectively the command process processing the batch file and is processed line by line after started background command process terminated itself.

**FOR** used with option `/F` always ignores empty lines. This does not matter here because of **DIR** does not output empty lines on being executed with option `/B`.

`for /F` splits up a non-empty line by default into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and assigns by default just first space/tab separated string to the specified loop variable which is here the loop variable `G`. `for /F` ignores by default additionally also a processed line if the first substring after splitting the line up starts with a semicolon because of `eol=;` is the default for end of line option.

So the command line `for /f %%G in ('dir *.rar /b') do` causes several problems on processing the list of directory entries output by **DIR**.

1. For a file/folder name containing a space just the first space/tab separated part of the file/folder name is assigned to loop variable `G` instead of complete name. For example a name like `My Archive.rar` results in just `My` is assigned to the loop variable `G`.
2. A file/folder name with one or more leading spaces is assigned to loop variable `G` without those leading spaces which means again that `G` does not hold complete name. For example a name like   `TwoLeadingSpaces.rar` results in getting assigned to loop variable `G` just `TwoLeadingSpaces.rar` without the two leading spaces and the file (or folder) is not found on referencing the value of loop variable `G`.
3. A file/folder name with a semicolon at beginning after zero or more leading spaces is completely ignored by command **FOR** for further processing. For example names like `;Test.rar` (name beginning with a semicolon) or  `;TestWithALeadingSpace.rar` (name with leading space and a semicolon) are completely ignored for further processing by **FOR**.

The points 2 and 3 are usually no problem as file/folder names with leading space(s) or a semicolon at beginning are really very rare. But a file/folder name with a space occurs very often.

A solution would be using **FOR** without option `/F`:

```
for %%G in (*.rar) do
```

**FOR** searches now itself for **non-hidden files** (not directories) in the current directory matching the wildcard pattern `*.rar` and assigns a found file name without path to loop variable `G` and next runs the command(s) after `do`. There is no additional command process started and there is no substring splitting done.

But there is a problem with this very simple solution in case of the commands executed for each found file name delete, move or rename files matched by the wildcard pattern `*.rar`. The list of directory entries matching the wildcard pattern changes on each iteration of the body of the **FOR** loop while command **FOR** queries the directory entries one after the other with executing the commands between each directory query. This is especially on FAT16, FAT32 and exFAT drives a real problem, but can result also in unexpected behavior on NTFS drives.

Whenever a **FOR** loop is used to process a list of files which could change during the iterations of the loop because of deleting, moving or renaming the files matched by a wildcard pattern, it is better to process a list of files loaded completely into memory before first iteration of the loop.

So a better solution for this task with the requirement to delete a RAR archive file after successful extraction is:

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.rar /A-D /B 2^>nul') do
```

The **DIR** option `/A-D` results in ignoring directory entries with attribute directory. So output by **DIR** are just file names matching the wildcard pattern in current directory including hidden RAR archive files.

`2^>nul` is passed as `2>nul` to the background command process which results in redirecting the error message output by **DIR** on no `*.rar` file found to device **NUL** to suppress it.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The `for /F` option `eol=|` changes the end of line character from `;` to `|`. No file name can have a vertical bar in its file name according to Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). So no file name is ignored anymore by **FOR** because of end of file option.

The `for /F` option `delims=` changes the delimiters list for line splitting into substrings to an empty list of delimiters which disables the line splitting behavior completely. So a file name with one or more spaces anywhere in file name is assigned completely to the specified loop variable `I`.

---

The task description is not very clear regarding to what to do depending on the batch file arguments, especially if the first argument is not case-insensitive `test`.

However, the following commented batch file could be working for this task on being called with first argument being `test` or with no arguments at all or with `/?` as first argument.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1" == "" goto OutputHelp
if "%~1" == "/?" goto OutputHelp
if /I not "%~1" == "test" goto MoreCode

set "SourceFolder=%~2"
if defined SourceFolder goto CheckFolder

echo(
echo Error: Folder with RAR or PDF file(s) not specified on command line.
goto OutputHelp

:CheckFolder
rem Replace all forward slashes by backslashes in folder name.
set "SourceFolder=%SourceFolder:/=\%"
rem Append a backslash to folder path if it does not end with a backslash.
if not "%SourceFolder:~-1%" == "\" set "SourceFolder=%SourceFolder%\"
rem Check the existence of the source folder.
if exist "%SourceFolder%" goto ProcessFolder

echo(
echo Error: Folder "%SourceFolder%" does not exist.
goto OutputHelp

:ProcessFolder
rem Get full qualidfied folder name, i.e. the folder name
rem with its absolute path and ending with a backslash.
for %%I in ("%SourceFolder%") do set "SourceFolder=%%~fI"

rem Define the destination folder for the PDF files extracted from the
rem RAR archive file(s) in source folder or copied from source folder.
set "DestinationFolder=C:\Temp\Test\"

rem Search for all *.rar files in folder passed with second argument and
rem extract all *.pdf files in each RAR archive file to the configured
rem destination folder. Rar.exe creates the destination folder automatically
rem if it is not already existing. The batch file is halted after processing
rem a RAR file on which Rar.exe exited with a value greater 0. Read the exit
rem codes documentation of Rar.exe at bottom of text file Rar.txt for more
rem information about the RAR exit codes. See Rar.txt also for the meaning
rem of the few RAR switches used here.

set "RarFileCount=0"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SourceFolder%*.rar" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do (
    set /A RarFileCount+=1
    "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" e -cfg- -idcdp -or -- "%SourceFolder%%%I" *.pdf "%DestinationFolder%"
    if not errorlevel 1 (del /A /F "%SourceFolder%%%I") else echo(& pause
)

if %RarFileCount% == 0 goto CheckFiles
if %RarFileCount% == 1 (set "PluralS=") else set "PluralS=s"
echo(
echo Info: Processed %RarFileCount% *.rar file%PluralS% in folder "%SourceFolder%".
goto EndBatch

:CheckFiles
echo Info: There are no *.rar files in folder "%SourceFolder%".
if exist "%SourceFolder%*.pdf" goto CopyFiles

echo Info: There are no *.pdf files in folder "%SourceFolder%".
goto EndBatch

:CopyFiles
rem Copy all PDF files in source folder to destination folder. xcopy.exe
rem creates destination folder automatically if it is not already existing.
echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%SourceFolder%*.pdf" "%DestinationFolder%" /C /I /Y
goto EndBatch

:OutputHelp
echo(
echo Usage: %~n0 [TEST] [Folder with RAR or PDF file(s)]
echo(
echo    If the first argument is case-insensitive TEST, the second argument
echo    specifies the folder containing the RAR files to extract or the PDF
echo    files to copy to destination folder. The folder must be specified
echo    with first argument being TEST.
echo(
pause
goto EndBatch

:MoreCode
rem Add here the code to execute on first argument is not case-insensitive TEST.

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `xcopy /?`
- `"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" /?`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
@echo off
set "cat=%~1"
IF "%cat%"=="test" ( 
  for %%G in (*.rar) do set filename=%%G
)
echo %filename%
```

Here wildcard is used to get all the rar files in the directory.